# Can't find "Gallery" field type while working with custom fields on ACF on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXb33.png)I cannot find the Gallery field type so that I could integrate multiple images to my WordPress post through a field. Why is this so ?

Answer (score 1):

1). Copy the navz-photo-gallery folder into your wp-content/plugins folder.

2). Activate the Advanced Custom Fields: Photo Gallery plugin via the plugins admin page.

3). Create a new field via ACF and select the Photo Gallery type.

4).Please refer to the description for more info regarding the field type settings.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/navz-photo-gallery/